# .NET Core Entity Framework InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I  have a simple model

```
[Table("InterfaceType")]
public class InterfaceType
{
    [Key]
    public int InterfaceTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

and in my DbContext

```
public DbSet<InterfaceType> InterfaceTypes { get; set; }
```

and in my controller

```
List<InterfaceType> types = _context.InterfaceTypes.FromSql(
            "SELECT * FROM [Interfaces].[Control].[InterfaceType]").ToList();
```

Which is returning the error:

> InvalidOperationException: The required column 'InterfaceID' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.

I am using FromSql in other methods similar to this with no issue although those models do contain an InterfaceId.  Why does this operation expect an InterfaceId when it is not in the model.  I have also tried the below with the same result.

```
List<InterfaceType> types = _context.InterfaceTypes.FromSql(
            "SELECT InterfaceTypeId, Description FROM [Interfaces].[Control].[InterfaceType]").ToList();
```

I have also tried:

```
interfacesOverview.SelectedInterface.InterfaceTypes = _context.InterfaceTypes.ToList();
```

After declaring via the fluent api:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       modelBuilder.Entity<InterfaceType>().ToTable("InterfaceType", "Control");
    }
```

with the same result.

For clarity here is the table in MSSQL:

```
    CREATE TABLE [Control].[InterfaceType](
    [InterfaceTypeId] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](25) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_InterfaceType] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [InterfaceTypeId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

### UPDATE

I've looked at the SQL that EF is generating:

```
    SELECT [i].[InterfaceTypeId], [i].[Description], [i].[InterfaceID] FROM [Control].[InterfaceType] AS [i]
```

Where is it getting InterfaceID from?

Comment: Why are you using `FromSql` anyway?

Comment: Yes that would probably/possibly solve the problem (as I said I'm new to this) but this should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: Is the column in the table named exactly "InterfaceTypeId' or is it "InterfaceID"?

Comment: InterfaceTypeId

Comment: Is there perhaps some fluent api configuration that maps `InterfaceTypeId` to column name `InterfaceId`?

Comment: I don't know if it will help, but why are you selecting columns from `[Interfaces].[Control].[InterfaceType]` instead of `[Control].[InterfaceType]`?

Comment: @RedEyedMonster, don't you have somewhere else ```Interface``` class which has a relation to ```InterfaceType``` table?

Comment: There is an interface class but no defined relationship although InterfaceTypeId is one of the fields in that class.

Comment: @RedEyedMonster, question no 2: Don't you have any pending migrations or wasn't this field there in previous version of the model

Comment: It was never in this model

Comment: Can you temporarily remove `InterfaceTypeId` property from `Interface` class, update database and run the query again?

Comment: Compare columns types of table in db and properties of class in your project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Where is it getting InterfaceID from?

First, it should be clear that it's not coming from the shown "simple" (but apparently incomplete) model.

The EF generated SQL clearly indicates that you didn't rename the PK property generated column, also there is no `Discriminator` column, so it cannot be coming from inheritance. And the chance that you have explicitly defined a shadow property called `InterfaceID` and not noticing it is small.

All this, along with the fact that the name `InterfaceID` matches one of the EF Core conventional names for FK property/column name for me is a clear indication of a conventional FK introduced by a relationship. For instance having a second model like this:

```
public class Interface
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    // or
    // public int InterfaceID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<InterfaceType> InterfaceTypes { get; set; }
}
```

As explained in the [Relationships - Single Navigation Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#single-navigation-property) EF Core documentation topic:

> Including just one navigation property (no inverse navigation, and no foreign key property) is enough to have a relationship defined by convention.

and the accompanying example shows `Blog` / `Post` model with only `public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }` property in `Blog` highlighted.

All EF Core runtime behaviors are based on model metadata. It doesn't matter what is the structure of your database, the more important is what EF Core thinks it is base on your model classes, data annotations and fluent configuration, and if that matches the database schema. The easier way to check that is to generate migration and check if it matches the database schema or not.

So if the relationship is intentional, then you have to update your database to match your model. Otherwise you need to update your model to match the database - by removing or ignoring the collection navigation property (or correcting the invalid data annotation / fluent configuration causing the discrepancy).

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of this problem, is that EF created a [Shadow Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties)
inside your model class, possibly by partially discovered relationship in your `Interface` model.

Also I feel there is a mismatch between your ModelSnapshot used by EFCore and real state of tables in Database (possibly by pending migration). Double check, how your `InterfaceType` in `<YourDbContext>ModelSnapshot.cs`, and check if there's a property you are missing.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you also have an "Interface" table registered in the context that holds a reference to the InterfaceType. Interface would have an InterfaceTypeId field declared, however with EF, if you are using HasOne with a ForeignKey, check that you haven't accidentally assigned something like:

`.HasOne(x => x.InterfaceType).WithOne().HasForeignKey<InterfaceType>("InterfaceId");`

In the case of an Interface having an InterfaceType it would be mapped more like:

`.HasOne(x => x.InterfaceType).WithMany();`

This might have crept into one of your other associated entities. Often these are typos where the autocomplete picked the wrong type without you noticing. If that mapping exists on any of your classes, EF will be expecting to find an InterfaceId column on InterfaceType. Do a search on `HasForeignKey<InterfaceType>` and see if that turns up anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: This was my guess as well, maybe OP can post the modelbuilder or look at "View dependencies" in smss

Answer (score 1):

First why not use

`List<InterfaceType> types = _context.InterfaceTypes.ToList();`

Secondly did you apply any changes to the model and forget to persist this to the database, as it could be that the column is correct in your class but not in your database. This is often something i forget to do when using a Code-FirstModel.

Here is some additional info on FromSQL :- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

More detail on migration here:- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/

I hope this helps.

Comment: Using your suggestion I get SqlException: Invalid object name even though it is correct.  There has to be something wrong with the wiring here but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: @RedEyedMonster, did you try gerryc.inc's suggestion and check that the fluent API is not doing any sort of mapping. This can be seen in the same class where your db context is.

Comment: Yes the config is correct, I have many other queries and calls to stored procs that all work OK

Comment: @RedEyedMonster I see you edited your original question, added schemas and db names?

Comment: Just trying to make it as understandable as possible, I'm beginning to wonder if it is anything at the db end but can't see it e.g. permissions etc..  If it didn't work for other queries it would make more sense but it is just this one table.

Comment: @RedEyedMonster Ok, another tip seeing as you are using Schema's make sure you point your object to the correct schemas in you dbcontext and use the fluent API for this, then thry again using List<InterfaceType> types = _context.InterfaceTypes.ToList();

Comment: yep, so I did this:  modelBuilder.Entity<InterfaceType>().ToTable("InterfaceType", "Control"); and then as suggested List<InterfaceType> types = _context.InterfaceTypes.ToList(); and I get the original error i.e. The required column 'InterfaceID' was not present.  The wood and the trees I'm sure

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to add *DatabaseGeneratedAttribute*

```
[Table("InterfaceType")]
public class InterfaceType
{
   [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity),Key()]
   public int InterfaceTypeId { get; set; }
   ...
```

Comment: Sadly still gives the same result

Answer (score 0):

Just to check if there is a way I can reproduce, I created a sample `.NET Core Console application` to check this and in my case, I am able to retrieve the data from DB without any exception.

> I understand you have other models where the same code is working, 
>   and if you move the problematic code outside your original solution, you might be
>   able to figure out if there is something obvious you are missing.

I tried to follow your code as closely as possible in attempt to reproduce this issue, where some of the things I had to change.

I don't know which `.NET Core` and `EF Core` versions you have used. In my sample, I used:

1. .NET Core 2.2
2. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.2
3. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 2.2
4. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.2
5. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.2

I created:

1. Model Class as per your sample
2. Context Class with OnModelCreating per your sample

Executed following `dotnet core` commands in the same order as listed below:

1. `dotnet restore`
2. `dotnet build`
3. `dotnet ef migrations add InitMgr`
4. `dotnet ef database update`
5. Added few test records in the table

Copied your records retrieval code, removed "[Interfaces]" from the query and debugged the code below.

```
        var _context = new InterfaceTypeContext ();
        List<InterfaceType> types = _context.InterfaceTypes.FromSql ("SELECT * FROM [Control].[InterfaceType]").ToList ();
```

I was able to retrieve the data from DB.

[image]

> It would also help if you share [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable
>   example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for someone to debug and help you find a solution for
>   this.

Answer (score 0):

The following has worked for me:

Insert some data:

```
insert into [Control].[InterfaceType] values (1, 'Desc1'), (2, 'Desc2');
```

C#:

```
class SOContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<InterfaceType> InterfaceTypes { get; set; }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var conn_string = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Interfaces;Trusted_Connection=Yes;";
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(conn_string);
    }
}

[Table("InterfaceType", Schema = "Control")]
public class InterfaceType
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None), Key]
    public byte InterfaceTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() =>
        $"Id: {InterfaceTypeId} | Description: {Description}";
}

// Output:
// Id: 1 | Description: Desc1
// Id: 2 | Description: Desc2
```